# Unknown class al usar TextInputLayout en MainActivity

Tags: android, validación, class

uso `Android Studio 3`, estoy tratando de hacer validación, en la primera parte según un tutorial que vi, se hace esto:

```
package com.example.jhon.cesde5;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputLayout impEditDescripcion, impEditDocIdent, impEditPassword, impTextNombre, impTextApellido, impTextDireccion;
    TextInputLayout impTextTelefono, impTextFechaIngreso, impTextEstado;
    EditText editTextDescripcion, editTexDocIdent, editPassword, textNombre, textApellido, textDireccion, textTelefono,
    texEstado, textFechaIngreso;
    Button butIngresar, butIngresarCliente;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    impEditDescripcion=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditDescripcion);
```

Obtengo este error en la última línea:

> Unknown class impEditDescripcion

Comment: La obtención de la referencia de tu elemento debe realizarse dentro de onCreate() ya que es ahí donde cargas el layout activity_main.xml .

Comment: OK. Gracias. Ahora funciona

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error es porque estas intentando declarar la variable en un sitio que no le corresponde. Para declarar los elementos del layout hay que cargar la vista en el método on create y seguido declarar los elementos tal que así:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        impEditDescripcion=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditDescripcion);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas tratando de obtener la referencia del TextInputLayout fuera del método `onCreate()` lo cual es incorrecto:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    impEditDescripcion=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditDescripcion);
```

El método `onCreate()` indica a través del método `setContentView()` el layout de tu Activity y que contiene generalmente los elementos que se mostrarán en la UI.

La obtención de la referencia de tu `TextInputLayout` se debe realizar dentro de `onCreate()` de esta forma :

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        impEditDescripcion=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditDescripcion);


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Debes codificar dentro del onCreate caso contrario create un metodo y hacer el llamado en el onCreate, de esta forma:

```
package com.example.jhon.cesde5;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputLayout impEditDescripcion, impEditDocIdent, impEditPassword, impTextNombre, impTextApellido, impTextDireccion;
    TextInputLayout impTextTelefono, impTextFechaIngreso, impTextEstado;
    EditText editTextDescripcion, editTexDocIdent, editPassword, textNombre, textApellido, textDireccion, textTelefono,
    texEstado, textFechaIngreso;
    Button butIngresar, butIngresarCliente;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        impEditDescripcion=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditDescripcion);
    }
```

o puedes utilizar de este modo:

```
package com.example.jhon.cesde5;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.sax.StartElementListener;
    import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.util.Patterns;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextInputLayout impEditDescripcion, impEditDocIdent, impEditPassword, impTextNombre, impTextApellido, impTextDireccion;
        TextInputLayout impTextTelefono, impTextFechaIngreso, impTextEstado;
        EditText editTextDescripcion, editTexDocIdent, editPassword, textNombre, textApellido, textDireccion, textTelefono,
        texEstado, textFechaIngreso;
        Button butIngresar, butIngresarCliente;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initComponent();
        }

       public void initComponent(){
            impEditDescripcion=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditDescripcion);
       }
```